# How to share the page to facebook / twitter with different language?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, twitter, share

I am using codeigniter and the language is determine by the session.

I wrrite the meta data, facebook / twitter grab the data and share the page:

```
        echo "<meta name='twitter:card' content='summary' />";
        echo "<meta property='og:title' content='" . $video->{set_lang("title")} . "' />";
        echo "<meta property='og:description' content='" . $video->{set_lang("description")} . "' />";
        echo "<meta property='og:image' content='" . (isset($video->image_url) ? site_url("thumbnail/" . $video->image_url) : $video->thumbnail) . "' />";
```

The set_lang function is to check the session like this:

```
function set_lang($var) {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $lang = $CI->session->userdata('site_lang');
    if ($lang == "english") {
        return $var;
    } else if ($lang == "zh_tw") {
        return $var . "_tw";
    } else if ($lang == "zh_cn") {
        return $var . "_cn";
    }
}
```

The share function work fine in the browser, however, I would like to share the link by mobile app too. Since the app contain no session it can not check language. Also, if I put the parameter in the link, eg.

http://example.com/video/view/1/english

Then my share link will also fix the language.

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the information about the language inside the link like this `http://example.com/video/view/1/english`,  then the language info can be taken as a parameter by the controller (it would have helped if you mentioned what was the controller here, but let's say it's `view()`), and use it, like this:

```
function view($param1, $lang = false){

}
```

You can then modify function `set_lang()`, to take two parameters, `$var`(the original one) and `$lang`:

```
function set_lang($var, $lang = false){
   if(!$lang){
       $CI = & get_instance();
       $lang = $CI->session->userdata('site_lang');
   }
   if ($lang == "english") {
       return $var;
   } else if ($lang == "zh_tw") {
       return $var . "_tw";
   } else if ($lang == "zh_cn") {
       return $var . "_cn";
   }
}
```

This way, if the language is set in url, `$CI->session->userdata('site_lang')` will be ignorred.

Now if you want to pass `$lang` to your view, you do it like this:

```
function view($param1, $lang = false){
     $local['lang_by_url'] = $lang;   
     $this->load->view('the_view', $local);
}
```

And in your view:

```
echo "<meta name='twitter:card' content='summary' />";
echo "<meta property='og:title' content='" $video->{set_lang("title", $lang_by_url)} . "' />";
...
...
```

It's a little hacky, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you explored the [internationalization](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization#objects) documentation?

Using `og:locale:alternate` meta tags (one pointing to each language) should show the link in the Facebook users native language across Facebook.com.

Try it out :D

Comment: That works for Open Graph stories only. For normal posts that include a link, it doesn’t work – the post will always show the link details in the language that Facebook got when requesting the link details, alternate locales are not taken into account in that context. (This has been confirmed by Facebook engineers.)

Comment: Have you attempted to pre-scrape multiple locales of the linked page? Did that make a difference?

Comment: Yeah, doesn’t make a difference. As I said, for normal posts it is not implemented as of now, as confirmed by an FB employee.

Comment: You need to set og tag <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" /> . also did you try setting the page language in the html tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp